# Python Pandas: extract data from a cell and turn it into a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a somewhat messed up dataset with this pattern:

```
ID       Value
abc      (john:10),(albert:5),(hanna:7) ...
def      (frank:5),(dave:8),(ben:11) ...
```

I of course would rather have this data in this format:

```
ID       Value1  Value2
abc      john       10
abc      albert      5
abc      hanna       7
def      frank       5
def      dave        8
def      ben         11
```

However, I'm somewhat stuck in terms of how to do it?
The only solution I could come up with was looping through and adding very new datapoint to a new dataframe.

Is there maybe a better & more efficient approach?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `str.extractall`

We can extract all the occurrences of a **regex** pattern, from the strings in column `Value`

```
df.set_index('ID')['Value'].str.extractall(r'\((\w+):(\d+)\)').droplevel(1)
```

---

```
          0   1
ID             
abc    john  10
abc  albert   5
abc   hanna   7
def   frank   5
def    dave   8
def     ben  11
```

**Regex details:**

- `\(`: Matches the character `(` literally
- `(\w+)` : First capturing group

  - `\w+` : Matches one or more word characters
- `:` : Matches the character `:` literally
- `(\d+)` : Second capturing group

  - `\d+` : Matches one or more digits
- `\)` : Matches the character `)` literally

See the online [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x0q8jP/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `explode` and `str.extract`:

```
df = df.assign(Value = df.Value.str.split(',')).explode('Value')
df[['Value_1', 'Value_2']] = df.Value.str.extract(pat=r'\((\w+):(\d+)\)')
df = df.drop('Value', axis =1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    ID Value_1 Value_2
0  abc    john      10
0  abc  albert       5
0  abc   hanna       7
1  def   frank       5
1  def    dave       8
1  def     ben      11
```